# If $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{2}+1-x\int_0^x g(t) dt$ and $g(x)=x-\int_0^1f(u) du $ then the minimum distance between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The way I thought to solve this problem is to find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ . So $$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{2}+1-x\left[\int_0 ^x\left(x-\int_0^1 f(u) du\right)\right]$$ This gives $$f(x)=1-x^2\int_0^1 f(u) du$$ Now dividing both sides by $x^2$ and differentiating we get $$f'(x)-\frac2 x f(x)=-\frac 2 x$$
Solving this we get $$f(x)= 1+Cx^2$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Now my question is how do I find $C$? I do not have a initial condition. or maybe $C$ isn't required after all? It seems I cannot solve for minimum distance without $C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\int_{0}^{1}f(u) du=A \implies g(x)=x-A$, then
$$f(x)=x^3/3+1-x\int_{0}^{x} (A-x) dx \implies f(x)=1+Ax^2.$$
Next, $$ A=\int_{0}^{1} (1+A x^2) dx \implies f(x)=1+3x^2/2, g(x)=x-3/2$$
To find the distance between the parabola and line we set $f'(x)=3x=1 \implies x=1/3, y=7/6.$ So the distance of the point $(1/3,7/6)$ from the line $y=x-3/2$ is
$d=\frac{7}{3\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 1):

You have $f(x)=1-x^{2}\int_0^{1} f(u)du$. Just plug in $f(x)=1+Cx^{2}$ into this you can easily see that $C=-\frac 3  4$.

Comment: Ah right! How did I miss that? Thanks!